# Task 'kotlinCompilerClasspath' not found in project ':debug'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Android project failed during a build.

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':debug:compileDevelopDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debug:kotlinCompilerClasspath'.
> Could not download kotlin-script-runtime-1.5.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.5.10)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-script-runtime/1.5.10/kotlin-script-runtime-1.5.10.jar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-script-runtime/1.5.10/kotlin-script-runtime-1.5.10.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Comment: it seems like it is trying to download files from bintray during the buld, but we do not have control over it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.